# Does 'value' have negative meaning in this speech?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “If you spend your life *valuing* yourself, dependent on how others
>   say you, then you’ll live a life buffeted by a lot of extreme
>   emotions, even if you don’t try and become Prime Minister.” (Julia
>   Gillard)
>
> [source: Aussie 7 News](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/152) (This is part of [the original](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErQ-KVtTnE8))

It seems ‘value’ is used in negative meaning, judging by the latter part of her saying. Does the word, value, have two aspect – negative and affirmative – in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two problems with the transcription probably added to your confusion; there should not be a comma after *yourself*, and it should be *see you* not *say you*. The modified relevant section of the text:

> If you spend your life valuing yourself dependent on how others see you,

What's being said is, if you *value yourself based on how others see you*, or based on others' opinions of who you are, then you will live an unhappy life.  You can never make everyone happy, so if your self-worth is determined by others' opinions you're never going to be happy.

So there's nothing negative about the word *value*.  You can either value yourself highly or poorly (or any number of things in between).  But if you value yourself based on others you will always have poor self-esteem, and thus be unhappy.